# Cytoscape.js, nodes aren't getting selected with Chrome

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

In cytoscape.js I have a network, and when I select a node, normally the color of the inner circle, which is green, should turn black, like this in Mozilla Browser:

[image]

But when I try the same network in Google Chrome it doesn't work, I just get this, like I was moving the node, not clicking it:

[image]

Is there a compatibility problem between Chrome and cytoscape.js?
Or anybody has any other ideas of why the selection could not be working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to this: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/876

If there is a bug in a particular version of a browser on the browser side, it's hit or miss whether there can be a workaround.  You may want to file an issue with more details: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new